# Properties Class vs System Properties

Tags: java, properties-file

I just read that it is possible to store key/value pairs (properties) using the `Properties` class, which is a subclass of the `HashTable`. However, I have also read that you can store properties directly using `System.setProperty`.

So which one do I use? What are the real use-cases of each?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

`property` is `Java.lang.System` class type of static member variable, it is `java.util.Properties` type. So, `System.setProperty(key)` is just the `property` setter method. `Hashtable` is a way of store the data,you can also consider it as a database.

You should use the `System.setProperty(key)` and `System.getProperty(key)` to write and read the Key/Value.

```html
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PropertiesTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        throws Exception {

        // set up new properties object
        // from file "myProperties.txt"
        FileInputStream propFile =
            new FileInputStream( "myProperties.txt");
        Properties p =
            new Properties(System.getProperties());
        p.load(propFile);

        // set the system properties
        System.setProperties(p);
        // display new properties
        System.getProperties().list(System.out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer, however, I was asking about the differences between using the Properties class and using the System Properties instead. I am actually already aware of the code that you have provided as an example.... but it doesn't elaborate on their respective use-cases.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see `System.setProperty()` uses a `java.util.Properties` class, so they are using the same backing class. However the properties class that `System.setProperties()` uses is retrieved from the VM, have a look at the [documentation for System.getProperties()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties()) for more information on the properties set.

You probably need to consider what you are trying to achieve by setting a system property, as generally they are runtime variables describing versions and paths for the system.

In all the applications I have seen the System.properties are used as a read only list, should you want to write your properties out somewhere for the use of the system you would probably be better off putting it in a database table (if you are going to be changing these options at runtime) and working with it like that. You might want to try using a properties file if it's a relatively static list of program options that you need to be able to be different on different instances of your application, so maybe for something like branding.

The main purpose of the `Properties` class is to be able to serialise the list key-value list into a stream see the [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) class

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to modify many properties, it's better to use `System.setProperty(key, value)` than alternatives like `System.setProperties(props)` or `System.getProperties().setProperty(key, value)`. The difference is how `SecurityManager` handles these calls. For `System.setProperty(key, value)` the `SecurityManager` is asked for permission to modify a single specific `key`. For `System.getProperties()` call the `SecurityManager` is asked for permission to read/write anything. So it's possible that the installed `SecurityManager` protects only some of properties, thus `setProperty(key, value)` will succeed, but `getProperties().setProperty(key, value)` will fail.

If you need to read the specific property, always use `System.getProperty(key)` instead of `System.getProperties().getProperty(key)`. If installed `SecurityManager` disables property writing, but enables property reading, then the second call will fail.